PayPal receiving order not approved even onApprove function triggered
Trying to test sandbox createOrder Capture Order with angular
Receiving "Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment"
Order is created correctly.
Angular code
try {
      this.paypal = await loadScript({ clientId : clientId  });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("failed to load the PayPal JS SDK script", error,HttpStatusCode);
    }
    
    if (this.paypal) {
        try {
            await this.paypal.Buttons({
              
              style: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                color: 'gold',
              },
              createOrder : this.createOrderPaypal(),// this returns orderData.id from backend
              onApprove : (data: any, actions: any) => {
                //actions.order.capture().then(this.approveOrderPaypal())
                this.approveOrderPaypal(data.orderID)
              },


            }).render("#buttonPaypal");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("failed to render the PayPal Buttons", error);
        }
    }

backend dotnet code:
private async Task<dynamic> _CreateOrder(PayPalOrder newOrder,string _paypalClientId, string _paypalClientSecret, string _base)
            {
                  var accessToken = await GenerateAccessToken(_paypalClientId,_paypalClientSecret,_base);
                  var url = $"{_base}/v2/checkout/orders";
                  var payload = new
                  {
                        intent = "CAPTURE",
                        
                        purchase_units = new[]
                        {
                              new
                              {
                                    description = newOrder.Description,
                                    amount = new
                                    {
                                          currency_code = newOrder.CurrencyCode,
                                          value = newOrder.Value
                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  };

                  .....

                  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                  return await HandleResponse(response);
            }

            private async Task<dynamic> _CaptureOrder(string orderID, string _paypalClientId, string _paypalClientSecret, string _base)
            {
                  var accessToken = await GenerateAccessToken(_paypalClientId,_paypalClientSecret,_base);
                  var url = $"{_base}/v2/checkout/orders/{orderID}/capture";

                  .....

                  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                  return await HandleResponse(response);
            }

Receiving "Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment"
Order is created correctly.

Code for this.approveOrderPayPal and this.createOrderPayPal may be relevant -- in particular, how is the id from data.id being given to approveOrderPayPal ? Are you sure the right id is being captured?

Yes, smth is wrong with the code. Checking paypal logs, two orders are created one with the original amount (eg : 60 $) and one with ( 0.1$ )and it captures the second somehow. Need to understand why

Well the code for those functions isn't in your question

createOrder : this.createOrderPaypal(),

createOrder should be set to a function (that returns), which normally would not itself be function evaluation/return. Instead try:
createOrder : this.createOrderPaypal,

It also appears wrong that this.approveOrderPayPal is not taking the id to capture as a parameter.
Both these functions should be included in the question for if anything else is wrong within them.

yes you are right. I forgot to pass data.orderID to OnApprove.  Regarding this.createOrderPaypal(), it returns orderID from backend, and pass it to createOrder

normally order creation should happen when a button is clicked, not on page load
